# "svn update" on a remote machine

Tags: svn, shell, cgi, batch

I need an ability to run "svn update" on a remote machine for a non-technical user, how would I go about it?

Our non-techincal users are using Windows XP and have Tortoise SVN client installed.

I'm thinking to do following but I'm not really in a favor for either so far...

- Batch (that runs locally on Windows)
- Shell (runs on a remote machine requires SSH access/client)
- CGI (that runs on a remote machine via web)

Comment: Are the users *so* non-technical that they're unable to right-click on the folder and do an SVN update themselves using TortoiseSVN's context menus?

Comment: svn update needs to happen on a remote machine not on their local workstations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyways, so what I end up doing is running CGI, so now they can hit that cgi that runs update

Comment: Whilst it's great that you have an answer to your problem, it would be better if you could elaborate on your solution so that others can benefit.

Answer (score -1):

If the remote machine is also running Windows and your users have privileges on the remote machine, I'd recommend giving [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) a look. Your command on the local machine would look something like:

```
psexec \\remotemachine -w C:\directory\on\remote\to\run\svnupdate\in svn update
```

You can specify a username and password with the -u and -p options, respectively.

svn.exe needs to be in the remote machine's PATH otherwise you have to specify its full path on the command line as well.

Wrap that line up in a .cmd file on your non-technical users' desktops and they just double click it to execute svn update on the remote machine.

Comment: remote machine is running Linux

Answer (score -1):

I typically use a telephone for this kind of thing. Non-technical users generally know how to use the mouse and the keyboard. I always say something like "I'm going to ask you to type in a command but please do not press the ENTER key until after you read it back to me and we verify that it is correct". Then I get them to open a command window, type C-D-SPACE-BACKWARDSSLASH-S-O-M-E-W-H-E-R-E-ENTER and then S-V-N-SPACE-U-P-D-A-T-E and ask them to read it back and verify that there is a space between the N and the U.